# Is it possible to use pom.xml properties and ignore command line arguments?

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I have a jenkins job that I don't have access to modify it, and it runs mvn command with arguments on a root pom.xml

I have access to change one of the modules, but I need to use the pom.xml properties not the ones sent by the command line.

Is this applicable?

Comment: Could you elaborate with a concrete example? Maybe we can work that specific example out...

Comment: The command line has sonar.sources argument as follows
mvn -f ..... -Dsonar.sources=. 

And I need to use another value in the pom.xml
<properties>
     <sonar.sources>./folderName</sonar.sources>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

And frankly, it sounds like a bad idea. Wouldn't it be better to talk to the person that handles the Jenkins job? It seems you should find a holistic approach.